# Django Rest Framework - return reverse foreign key property?

Tags: django-rest-framework

I think this is simple and probably a duplicate, but I cannot figure it out by looking at the documentation.

I have Django models as follows:

```
class Image(models.Model):
    manor = models.ForeignKey(Manor, related_name='image_for_manor')
    filename = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True, blank=True)

class Manor(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
```

I want the user to be able to query the Manor and see the related Image. I'd like this JSON to be returned:

```
{ 
   id: 572,
   image: 'my/filepath.png'
}
```

This is my view:

```
@api_view(['GET'])
def manor(request, id):
    mymanor = Manor.objects.get(id=id)
    serializer = ManorSerializer(mymanor)
    return JSONResponse(serializer.data)
```

And these are my serializers:

```
class ImageFilePathSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Image
        fields = ('filename',)

class ManorSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    image = ImageFilePathSerializer(source="image_for_manor")

    class Meta:
        model = Manor
        fields = ('id', 'image')
```

But this doesn't work: I get an empty dictionary for `image`. (Even if it weren't empty, I realise it wouldn't be right, because I don't want the `image` property to be a dictionary: I want it to be a string.)

How can I change this to be correct? I cannot work it out.

Comment: Does `image` always have to return the filename? DRF has an `ImageField` which can be configured to return the URL that points to the image. Also, does this have to be writable?

Comment: @KevinBrown thanks. It doesn't have to be writable, but it does have to return the filename (for consistency with an old API).

Answer (score 2):

As Kevin suggested , why dont you use ImageField which will give you url where your image is uploaded. although if you dont want to do that , here are some changes you have to do to get the result format you wanted.(Following solution assumes that only one image will be for one minor)

views.py ( why dont you ImageFilePathSerializer instead of another one as it also contains all the data you wanted)

```
@api_view(['GET'])
def manor(request, id):
    mymanor = Image.objects.get(manor__id=id)
    serializer = ImageFilePathSerializer(mymanor)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

serializers.py (add Id with filename in ImageFilePathSerializer)

```
class ImageFilePathSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Image
        fields = ('id', 'filename',)


class ManorSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    filename = serializers.ImageField(source="image_for_manor")

    class Meta:
        model = Manor
        fields = ('id', 'filename')
```